# GridView Data overlays with Header after vertical scrolling in Microsoft Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

I have a GridView that looks as follows:

```
<Page
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="View.ServiceModule"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:View"
xmlns:common="using:View.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding ServiceTasksFiltered}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="ServiceTasksFiltered">
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <GridView
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        x:Name="serviceTasksFilteredGridView"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,136,116,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceTasksFiltered, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="true"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="500"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Debitornr." TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Name" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Belegnr." TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Reaktionsdatum" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Priorität" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </Grid>
        </GridView.Header>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerNo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CustomerName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding DocumentNo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ResponseDateDisplay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding PriorityDisplay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0" 
                    Click="BackButton"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="Serviceaufgaben" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,30,40"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

When I try to scroll down to display the bottom rows, the top rows are being moved higher instead of disappearing. Please see the following picture for a better descirption:

[GridView with wrong scrolling settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBDT0.jpg)

As you can see the GridView is scrolled down and the rows are behind the header of the page.  I need them to disappear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't all of your layout XAML since at first glance I'm not seeing some things reflected in your screenshot. May want to share more to help troubleshoot or some slimmed down version capable of reproducing the while problem.

Comment: Okay, now it's updated to show the full XAML code.

Comment: Ya there's your problem. You have your GridView with Grid.RowSpan=2 and your title stuff would just be over the top of it. You could expect your problem with the way you have it declared to be laid out man because you're telling it to lay itself out that way, also in good formatting you wouldn't need all those big margins.

Comment: OH. Damnit, it's simply Grid.Row=2 and not RowSpan. Thanks, it's working fine now.

Comment: Haha, it's always something silly that gets us right? lol, the joys of development.

Comment: The joys of development indeed :D